# Values from Servlet Shows Through direct link Browser But not through code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using jquery mobile. When i use this link in browser :     http://****192/MLite/TransferIn2?imei=0000&username=usman&password=shafi, my code shows accurate result from servlet
but when i pass values from ajax , i do not get alert(data), One thing i make sure to you that servlet is recieving my request , but following ajax is not showing values from ajax.

...connection is successful
Ginesh bro the question is.. When i put my servlet in same localhost it works..but when i run from other pc it stops working in ajax,..but works  through direct url 
please help me..

```
$.ajax({


url : "http://19****/MLite/TransferIn2",

        type : "post",
        dataType : "json",
        data : {


            "username": amt,
                            "password":imei2

        },
        success : function(data) {

alert(data);


        },
        error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr);
            //setMessage("#transferout-msg", "Connection to Server    Failed");
            //$("#transferout-msg").html(xhr.status + ":" + thrownError);

        }


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.stringify for your data before you POST.

`data: JSON.stringify({
         "username": amt,
         "password":imei2
        });`

Comment: this is not issue man......on servlet file i am successgfully getting json..but not getting response in the ajax. I am getting response through direct link but not through ajax

Comment: @user2768215 Your direct link call from browser is HTTP-GET call, and the ajax call is POST. You might want to post your server side code if there is any difference in the processing logic. Try doing stringify and see if it works.

Comment: on server side i am using this logic :     Response.getParameter("username") and posting result in the form of Response.getWriter.write(result);...stringify thing is not working

Comment: I'm assuming it is "Request.getParameter" which you are referring to. It only reads the GET parameters ?username=value. You might want to add the server side logic in the original question.

Comment: if logic were incorrect then it should not show any response in direct link

Comment: remove dataType = json and change `data: 'username='+value+'&password='+value`. Yes Request.getParameter reads posts if you POST as standard form.

Comment: Ginesh bro the question is.. When i put my servlet in same localhost it works..but when i run from other pc it stops working in ajax,..but works  through direct url